# finding part of a string and using it as its own value in php

Tags: php, regex

In the example below can someone tell me how can i remove the number after no. and use it as a value?

No.311 11/12ozs

Comment: in the example the number would be 311.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = 'No.311 11/12ozs';
preg_match('/No\.([0-9]+)/is', $string, $matches);
// result would be in $matches[1]
```